# sql oracle, ALTER TABLE error

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

Here is ERD model of my DB:
[image: erd]

Here is create table codes i used so far:
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Gfwv2tca)

I have created all tables and now I'm trying to alter them to create  foreign keys, 
 but this alter doesn't work.

```
Alter table uskladnena_surovina add  foreign key  (datum_spotreby,id_dodavatela,id_suroviny) references ponukana_surovina    (datum_spotreby,id_dodavatela,id_suroviny) 
/
```

It says:

```
"DATUM_SPOTREBY": 
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you to post question with variables columns and whatever named in English so you would get faster reply.

Nevertheless it is not good idea to make Foreign key in `date data type`. Change to `int` maybe?

Comment: I will in the future use English, thanks. I added my CREATE TABLE code i used so far. Do you think that using DATE as foreign key makes this error? I googled for it and there wasnt any reason why i couldn't use it.

Comment: i forgot to add datum_Spotreby into uskladnena_surovina so obviously it couldnt work, now it works

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Oracle that you want to create a constraint.  To do this, you need to specify `add constraint` after `alter table ...`.  If you don't tell Oracle what you want to add to the table, it assumes you want to add a new column.

Try

```
Alter table uskladnena_surovina add constraint constraint_name foreign key  (datum_spotreby,id_dodavatela,id_suroviny) references ponukana_surovina    (datum_spotreby,id_dodavatela,id_suroviny)
```

/

You also have to give the constraint a name.  Feel free to change `constraint_name`.

Comment: i forgot to add datum_Spotreby into uskladnena_surovina so obviously it couldnt work, now it works
BTW, why is constraint necessary here? Wouldnt it work without it?

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry guys, 
i forgot to add datum_Spotreby into uskladnena_surovina so obviously it couldnt work, now it works